# Formating Python strings with \n

Tags: python, string, formatting

[image: im trying to make a board like that with strings] I am trying to format this string into a board using `\n`, there is syntax error somewhere but I don't know where!

```
f1= ("a"   "b"   "c" + "|"\n + "   -------------"+"\n" + "1  |",gameboard[0],"|",gameboard    [    1], "|" ,gameboard[2], "|"+"\n" + "2","|",gameboard[3],"|",gameboard[4], "|" ,gameboard[5],"|" +"\n" + "3","|",gameboard[6],"|",gameboard[7], "|" ,gameboard[8], "|"+"\n"+ "-------------")


gameboard = ['O', ' ', ' ', 'O', 'X', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'X']
print(f1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're in trouble already here:

```
f1= ("a"   "b"   "c" + "|"\n
```

Unfortunately, I can't guess what you *hope* that does.  It's equivalent to:

```
f1= ("abc|"\n
```

and you'd get the same error if you just put `\n` on a line by itself:

```
>>> \n
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

`\n` has no meaning outside of a quoted string.

Later:  Now that you added a picture, here's a start:

```
print "    a   b   c"
print "  -----------"
```

It's simple that way.  And it's just plain nuts ;-) to try to cram it all on one line. If you feel you must, those two prints are equivalent to this single - much harder to read - print:

```
print "    a   b   c\n  -----------"
```

Comment: I am trying to make a board with those values in them! the  \n was an attempt to make a new line

Comment: Sorry, I can't guess what that means. *Show* the exact output you want - *describing* it won't work well. But are you still stuck? You cannot use `\n` outside of a quoted string, so put `\n` inside a quoted string where you want it.

Comment: a tic-tac-toe board
with a  b  c on the top, 
---------------
   1
   2
   3

Comment: Same comment.  That's ambiguous.  Edit your question and **show** the exact output you want.  Exercise:  using one `print` statement, display `abc` on one line and `def` on the next line.  If you can't do that much, say so - and you'll never get something fancy to work until you can get something simple to work.

Comment: I added a picture on my edited version of my question.

Comment: Thanks! See my edit for a start.